# SOAP::Lite Generating <c-gensym .. > how do I get rid of it?

Tags: xml, perl, soap

Here's what I believe to be the relevant SOAP::Lite code

```
my $req3 = SOAP::Lite->new(
    readable => 1,
    autotype => 0,
    proxy    => 'https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor',
);

$req3->requestMessage(
    \SOAP::Data->new(
        name => 'item',
        attr => { foo => '0' },
        value => \SOAP::Data->new(
            name => 'foo',
            value => 1,
        ),
     ),
);
```

It's generating this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<requestMessage>
  <c-gensym9>
    <item foo="0">
      <foo>1</foo>
    </item>
  </c-gensym9>
</requestMessage>
</soap:Body>
```

I can't figure out why `<c-gensym9 />` is nested inside of `<requestMessage>` but I need to not be there. Can anyone explain why it's there? and how I can rewrite the code so that it isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look ma, no gensym

```
$req3->requestMessage(
   ## \SOAP::Data->new( ## this makes gensym
    SOAP::Data->new( ## no refref, no gensym
        name => 'item',
        attr => { foo => '0' },
        value => \SOAP::Data->new(
            name => 'foo',
            value => 1,
        ),
     ),
);
```

see also http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=906383

Comment: The problem is using the Perl ref `\`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code that we really need to help answer is the code you (quite unintentionally) excluded as `... # noisy SOAP::Data stuff`.

SOAP::Lite can be pretty gensym happy. It uses this tag whenever it doesn't understand the full data structure that it's trying to generate. So in your example, the SOAP::Data object defining the `requestMessage` tag seems to get passed an array when one isn't expected, hence the need for an unnamed (c-gensym5) intermediary tag.

Given what's generated above, it seems you may be trying to pass in an array with a hash `[ { data } ]`? Whenever SOAP::Lite feels a name should be present (i.e. `[ no name for hash --> { data } ]`) when none is provided, it will "gensym" to clarify the output. It could also be that SOAP::Lite is expecting something to be escaped that isn't escaped.

A very official looking post over at soaplite.com called [How do you turnoff the blasted c-gensym elements?](http://www.soaplite.com/2003/08/how_do_you_turn.html) is unfortunately not very helpful by itself (since the links out are dead) but the way back machine might be able to help.

I hope this helps. Sorry I can't be more specific!

Comment: yes I found that post... unfortunately it's links are dead... so it's useless.

Comment: The links in that article can be found at: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-hands-on-tour-of-soaplite/1045078 and http://web.archive.org/web/20070308122644/http://www.majordojo.com/archives/2003_04.html